# ¿Hay diferencia entre CompareInfo.IndexOf y CompareInfo.LastIndexOf si sólo se busca la existencia de una cadena?

Tags: string, .net, comparaciones

Me parece extremadamente raro que el siguiente código:

```
Dim Comp As CompareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo
Dim CompOpt As CompareOptions = CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace + CompareOptions.IgnoreCase + CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols
Dim Res As Integer = Comp.IndexOf(Texto1, Texto2, CompOpt)
```

Sea muchísimo más rápido que este código:

```
Dim Comp As CompareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo
Dim CompOpt As CompareOptions = CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace + CompareOptions.IgnoreCase + CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols
Dim Res As Integer = Comp.LastIndexOf(Texto1, Texto2, CompOpt)
```

Se está compilando en `.Net Framework 2.0.`

Comment: de cuanto es el largo de texto donde buscas para notar una diferencia en la respuesta ?

Comment: Pues es un documento PDF, de varias páginas. El caso es que no hay en ninguna página alguna coincidencia. Es por eso por lo que me extraña.

Answer (score 2):

La rapidez va a ser proporcional a cuento tenga que buscar para encontrar una coincidencia.

Si la cadena encuentra una coincidencia cuando empieza la cadena esta claro que el IndexOf va a devolver una respuesta enseguida.

Pero si buscas desde el final de la cadena y la coincidencia esta al principio de la misma va a demorarse hasta encontrarla.

Ubica una coincidencia en la búsqueda que este cerca del final y veras como los tiempos de respuesta cambian.